# Some animation requests in a Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, animation

I am making a flash card application. It shows the question and then a textbox for user input, all wrapped in a border or rectangle. So what I want is an animation that "flips" the rectangle or border upside-down and then their is text on the "back". Also, I want my application to APPEAR transition from one card to another by "flying off" the screen then "another" card comes in to replace the other one in the opposite direction. But actually I'm want just a little animation of the border or rectangle moving off the screen then coming back in, but in the opposite direction. Some help would be appreciated, like what kind of animation can accomplish this and maybe a small code sample to demonstrate. I am not asking you write all this, I think that would be a little rude (unless you really want to).

Comment: I have tried some things, but none of them work like I need it to. Some help would be appreciated. I am not asking you write all this, I think that would be a little rude (unless you really want to).

Comment: By help, I mean like what animations can do this? Maybe a small sample.

Comment: I totally will do this. I was in the process of creating this very application. Message me on gtalk and we can get going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you had a look at the Silverlight FX stuff? There might be some animations in there that are what you are looking for. There are also samples provided.

http://projects.nikhilk.net/SilverlightFX

Michael